# Facebook login Working debug build but not in release /production build Android/iOS?

Tags: android, facebook-login

Facebook login is working in android debug build. But when we make a release build it's throwing error on login. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add release 'release key hash'. Earlier, while you were creating a facebook basic settings you might have added your 'bebug key hash' in the Key hash filed. That is why it worked for debug build.
Same way in order to make the app work for production / release builds, you need to add the release key hash in the Key hash field.

How to create a release hash key?

Use this below command to generate the hash key

> echo your-release-sh1 | xxd -r -p | openssl base64
>
> echo 44:4E:48:99:19:50:5C:1F:63:A6:0F:F6:A1:C2:31:E5:01:38:55:6D | xxd -r -p | openssl base64